# Upgrading from 3.4.2

Tags: upgrade, backup

I recently took on a new client who runs a fairly active news site powered by WordPress. Part of what he wishes me to do is upgrade his WordPress version, something he's neglected to do since 3.4.2, my question is now:

Would it be feasible to upgrade to 3.8.1 straight away or should I opt for taking it in small steps (start by upgrading to 3.5, then 3.6 etc.)?

What would be appropriate security measures to take to prevent loss of data when doing this?

I reckon problems will arise with the active plugins and his current theme so will I need to do a full backup of all files a database dump or will less suffice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a backup and put it on a dev URL and test it to latest version.

What plugins are being used?

Comment: Sounds like a good way to go about it ;) See that's one of my headaches currently, figuring out which ones of the 34 plugins are actually being used, I see 4 sliders or so but I'm not really sure if more than 1 or 2 of them are being used ;)

Comment: If you setup on a dev then you can see what is used and what is not before you do the update.

Comment: True, I'll mark this as the correct answer since it seems to be the best way to go about it to avoid issues, thanks for your feedback :)